# Creating separated networks over WiFi and LAN

Tags: network-topology

I run a small business where we currently have a single network running between WiFi and Ethernet over an AirPort Extreme.  Most devices are using WiFi with only my main machine running via LAN.  I am preparing a major upgrade to our network, installing new LAN lines and setting up a distribution room.  My end goal is to create two separated networks, one for the office and one for guests, that are both Ethernet- and WiFi-capable: I.e., network X will run both over Ethernet and WiFi, and network Y will run over separate Ethernet and WiFi.  I am putting together a hardware budget and have a couple of topology scenarios in mind, but I'm not sure if they will work.

Scenario 1: Internet comes into distro room, AirPort Extreme creates and manages networks X and Y over both WiFi and Ethernet. Ethernet runs to dumb switch connecting all LAN jacks in building.

Scenario 2: Internet comes into distro room, AirPort Extreme creates and manages two WiFi networks X and Y and Ethernet network X.  Networks X are linked. Ethernet runs to managed switch that creates a second Ethernet network Y that does not connect to WiFi network Y.

I have thought of other scenarios, but these two seem to be the most probable. The only problem with Scenario 2 is that I would like to provide printer access to networks Y, but I can't think of how to provide access the same printer if the two are separated.

Will either of these scenarios work to meet my goal?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This discussion from 2010[(https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2385001?start=0&tstart=0) says that AirPort Extremes cannot handle making two separate networks with VLAN tagging, and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4731741?start=0&tstart=0) from Jan suggests that's still the case. If that's right, you won't be able to make two separate LAN+WiFi networks using one AirPort Extreme.

Scenario 2 might work, depending on how the APE handles the second guest network.

You would need a way of routing between the networks to handle printer connections - and then a firewall to allow some traffic through but keep the networks usefully separate - some kind of DNS server settings for Wide-Area-Bonjour if you wanted the printers to advertise themselves to Apple devices.

A reasonable design would be a switch, firewall and WAP with VLAN support. Have the main and guest networks on the same devices but logically separated, trunk them all together, have the firewall route and filter the traffic between them.

Comment: Okay, I was concerned that the Extreme might not handle this. In scenario 2, I can live without the printer to be shared across networks, which should make it easier. You say to have the firewall route/filter between the two networks, but isn't the function of a switch to pass data between all ports on the switch? How would a firewall filter traffic on the switch?

Comment: It seems that I could use a managed switch to create two networks, then add two WAPs that would be assigned each to a different network, set up as bridges to simply pass IP assignment to the switch. In this case, could a managed switch provide multiple IPs over a WAP, or would any access through a WAP in this setup utilize one IP?

Comment: `but isn't the function of a switch to pass data between all ports on the switch?` Between ports on a *network*. With VLANs you get multiple virtual networks on one switch, and the switch won't connect them together. So devices on each network talk to the firewall and the firewall can pass traffic back to the switch but on the other virtual network. As for the IP question, have two DHCP servers and two sets of IPs. Whether any given managed switch could do that is up to the manufacturer.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I knew that but didn't think it through. That should be enough to get me started, thanks for the help!